# switch loop doesnt recognize zero "0" php

Tags: php

I have this simple function to convert the number of comments of an user to types of members.

```
function checkMemberN($numMessages){
    $n= $numMessages;

    switch ($n) {
        case ($n<50): $type="New"; break;
        case ($n>=50 && $n<250):$type="Frequent";break;
        case ($n>=250 && $n<1000): $type="Master";break;
        default: $type="undefinded";
    }   

    return $type;   
}   

echo checkMemberN(0);
```

It looks like it doesn't recognize zero (0), because when I put 1 or a higher number it retrieves the correct user type. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do $n=intval($numMessages);

Comment: I think you want `switch(true)`. That being said, this is a terrible use-case for `switch`. Just use `if..else if..else`

Comment: Phil. haha. why a terrible use? I think it suits...how can I make it work?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka it doesnt work.

Comment: the funny thing is that it was working good a couple of days ago. now it doesnt work anymore...

Comment: Change it to `switch (true) {` and it works. Basically you're chasing a falsy value and that second condition is the first one to evaluate to false.

Comment: @JohnConde you are a genius. thank you +1 haha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `switch`, the first case which returns a value equal to the given one is selected. In this case, your argument (zero) is a false-y value. That's why the first case that returns `false` is chosen: "Frequent".
To fix it, you can do this:

```
if ($n<50) {
  $type = "New";
} else if ($n>=50 && $n<250) {
  $type = "Frequent";
} else if ($n>=250 && $n<1000) {
  $type = "Master";
} else {
 $type = "undefined";
}
```

If you still want to use `switch`, you can change the argument to `true`:

```
switch (true) {
    case ($n<50): $type="New"; break;
    case ($n>=50 && $n<250):$type="Frequent";break;
    case ($n>=250 && $n<1000): $type="Master";break;
    default: $type="undefinded";
}
```

Here, the first case which returns true will be used.